# How to get the response from the ajax request in another method after the response has been generated?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want the response generated from the method from which the request has been sent and I need that generated response in another method. Please, refer the below code for further reference.

```
function foodLog(){


   var data={ 
          servings : $('#demo_vertical').val(),
          calories : $('#calories').text(),
          carbs : $('#carbs').text(),    
   };

       $.ajax({  
             type : "POST",   
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
             dataType: "json",
             data : JSON.stringify(data),
             success : function(response) {

             },
             error : function(e) {  
                 alert("Object" +e);
                }  
               });  
   };
```

The response that is generated after the success I need to get in the below method. I wrote the below code but I am not able to get the response. Please help me out.

```
function getValues(){
var response = foodLog();
console.log(response)
  }
```

Comment: I see that in the success hadler you are redirecting to a different  URL. This will cause the response to be lost since you are moving to a different page. Also, if u want the response to be used in any other function, you can consider declaring a global variable and storing the response on to that.

Comment: @Vijeth thank you for your response , i have edited my question now I don't want to redirect to different page. Can you put some example code like how to catch that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a callback function to do this efficiently.

```
function foodLog(callback){  //sending callback function as input

  var data={ 
        servings : $('#demo_vertical').val(),
        calories : $('#calories').text(),
        carbs : $('#carbs').text(),    
  };

   $.ajax({  
         type : "POST",   
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
         dataType: "json",
         data : JSON.stringify(data),
         success : callback, //calling callback function when success
         error : function(e) {  
             alert("Object" +e);
            }  
           });  
}


//callback function to handle response
function callback(response){
     console.log(response);
}
```

---

When you want to call the function "foodLog",

```
foodLog(callback);
```

note: you will have to make sure the function callback is loaded before calling this. You may have to use,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    foodLog(callback);
});
```

Comment: I used the callback function as you suggested but i am getting undefined error in the line callback(response)

Comment: I tested this and works well for me. when do you call the function "foodlog"? Do you call it before the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one that u want

```
success : function(response) {  
                 if (response == true){  
                     window.location = "/fitbase/foodlog/create/";   
                     getValues(response);  
                }  

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValues(response){
  console.log(response);
}

function foodLog(){


 var data={ 
      servings : $('#demo_vertical').val(),
      calories : $('#calories').text(),
      carbs : $('#carbs').text(),    
 };

   $.ajax({  
         type : "POST",   
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
         dataType: "json",
         data : JSON.stringify(data),
         success : function(response) {
               getValues(response);
         },
         error : function(e) {  
             alert("Object" +e);
            }  
      });  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a variable this way.

```js
var foodLogResponse = '';

function foodLog(){


   var data={ 
          servings : $('#demo_vertical').val(),
          calories : $('#calories').text(),
          carbs : $('#carbs').text(),    
   };

       $.ajax({  
             type : "POST",   
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
             dataType: "json",
             data : JSON.stringify(data),
             success : function(response) {
                foodLogResponse = response;
             },
             error : function(e) {  
                 alert("Object" +e);
                }  
               });  
   };
```

else you can call the getValues function from within the success handler.

```js
success : function(response) {  
                 if (response == true){    
                     getValues(response);  
                }  

         }
```